# What is the next event in User Control after the parent page data control binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a user control that contains a **DropDownList** and some other controls. My user control has a public property called **UserName**, which will help to retrieve data to populate the dropdownlist.

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="ucDetails" UserName = '<%# Eval("UserName")%>' />
```

I found out when user control properties are being set. For the UserName (see the above example), the value is not being set during the page_Load of the usercontrol. It's being set during the DataBind event of the parent page, which is way after the page_load event of the User Control.

From the User Control prospective, what's the next closest event that I can still call the retrieve data then bind it to my DropDownList?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It looks like this is a user control that you are including in another data bound control? In that case it doesn't exist until the data bind of the parent control. I'm guessing your dropdown list depends on or is filtered in someway by the username? In which cases you could set the datasource to the appropriate list during rowdatabound perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the user control is itself part of a data-bound control. However, can you be a little explicit about the your suggestion regarding the RowDataBound?

Comment: What sort of data-bound control is your user control in? Depending on the type of data-bound control, you could either use the parent controls data bind event, or the data bind event for each row/item in the parent. With more info, I could provide an example.

Comment: I've using a Listview and an objectDatasource.

Comment: @Richard77 Was pulled away; essentially what TheRotag is showing in his answer is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to setup your drop down list during the data bound event for each item in your ListView, then on your ListView control, add a handler for the ItemDataBound event:

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="listView1_ItemDataBound">
```

Now, in that event handler in your code-behind, get the instance of your user control for this row/item:

```
protected void listView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var userControl = e.Item.FindControl("ucDetails") as UserControlClassName;
}
```

Then you can do whatever you need to on your user control, such as setting the UserName property on it and/or setting up your drop down list's items.

*Note*: if you need to set the property differently for each item, you can get the data object for the current item from the `ListViewItemEventArgs` object: `e.Item.DataItem as [whatever type the data item should be]`.

Alternatively, if you want to make sure that the drop down list is always populated *right after* the UserName is set, you could update the setter for the UserName property so that, if it's set to a valid username (not null or empty, etc.), it (the setter) calls a method to populate the drop down list. That way, it doesn't matter where in the page lifecycle you data bind your ListView. That might look something like this:

```
public string UserName
{
    get { return _username; }
    set
    {
        // Make sure new value is valid (not null/empty, exists, etc.)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            // Do something (throw exception, show error, etc.)
        else
        {
            _userName = value;
            SetupDropDownList();
        }
    }
}
private string _userName;
```